# How to print all the result without using Results.columnname in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

How to print all the result without using Results.columnname in ColdFusion

for ex:-

I have `<cfquery name="getProductId">
        select productId
         from product
        </cfquery>`

In Product Table i have 2 columns with product_name and Product_id.

How can I print them without using 
    getProductId.product_name
    getProductId.Product_id

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? If you are looking for a way to computationally output query results based on a query whose column names you do not know, such as...

```
<cfquery name="queryName" ...>
    select * from product
</cfquery>
```

...then you can use the `queryName.ColumnList` variable, which returns a comma separated list of all column names. You could subsequently iterate over this list, and output as required.

For example, to get a simple HTML table output:

```
<table border=1>
    <cfloop from="0" to="#queryName.RecordCount#" index="row">
        <cfif row eq 0>
            <tr>
                <cfloop list="#queryName.ColumnList#" index="column" delimiters=",">
                    <th><cfoutput>#column#</cfoutput></th>  
                </cfloop>
            </tr>
        <cfelse>
            <tr>
                <cfloop list="#queryName.ColumnList#" index="column" delimiters=",">
                    <td><cfoutput>#queryName[column][row]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfloop>
            </tr>
    </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</table>
```

Apologies if this isn't what you meant!

Comment: Again, there is no need for this `row` variable! Move the thead section outside the loop and do a query cfloop instead!

Comment: @Chris in this how can we extract out information of single column?? My means is it is giving me output as row wise which contains each column of a single row , how can I extract all columns of a row??

Answer (score 2):

Can you please clarify what means "without using column name"?

Maybe you want to use the **getProductId.ColumnList** attribute?

Small example from my old code that converts query to the array (a bit stripped details and changed var names, but shows the idea):

```
    <cfset arrRecordSet = ArrayNew(1)>

    <cfloop query="qGetSomething">
        <cfset record = StructNew()>
        <cfloop list="#qGetSomething.ColumnList#" index="field">
            <cfset record[field] = qGetSomething[field][qGetSomething.CurrentRow]>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(arrRecordSet,record)>
    </cfloop>
```

EDIT: enhanced example to get rid of row variable, as correctly noticed in comments.

Comment: The `row` variable is not needed. When doing a query loop, you've got the `QueryName.CurrentRow` variable already

Comment: @Peter, you're right. That's why I told that its a piece of the "old code" :)

Answer (score 2):

Query to HTML table? there's a tag for that!

`<CFTable>` FTW!

http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#cftable :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment to Chris's response, here's the simpler version with the missing thead/tbody tags added:

```
<cfoutput>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <cfloop index="ColName" list="#MyQuery.ColumnList#">
                    <th>#ColName#</th>
                </cfloop>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <cfloop query="MyQuery">
                <tr>
                    <cfloop index="ColName" list="#MyQuery.ColumnList#">
                        <td>#MyQuery[ColName][MyQuery.CurrentRow]#</td>
                    </cfloop>
                </tr>
            </floop>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```