# Looping Columns in coldfusion along with values in correct order

Tags: html, sql, coldfusion

Instead of hardcoding the columns from a query into a table I prefer to do it dynamically.
This is code I tweaked from another source. What I want to do is not only get the Columns in order, but also get the row values for each column as well. I can't seem to find an attribute that shows the actual row values for each column using this method, just the column names and type.

In the two cfloops the top one will represent the column name, while the bottom one will present the row value for that column.

```
cfset employeemeta=getMetaData(ShowDeletedData)>
 <Table border="1">
 <TR>
<h4>The Employees table has the following columns</h4>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(employeemeta)#">
    <cfoutput>
       <TD> #employeemeta[i].name# </TD>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</TR>
 <TR>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(employeemeta)#">
    <cfoutput>
       <TD> #employeemeta[i].name# </TD>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</TR>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print all the result without using Results.columnname in ColdFusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642831/how-to-print-all-the-result-without-using-results-columnname-in-coldfusion)

Comment: None of those examples would answer my question in particular because I'm asking for the Columns to stay in the order they are in within my database. Coldfusion places them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 5):

Something I learned from other people's answers on these forums is that ColdFusion has a function called getColumnList().  It returns an array of the column names in the order they appear.  I just ran this code to verify it.

```
<cfquery name="x" datasource="burns">
select 1 b, 2 a
from dual
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#x.getcolumnlist()#" metainfo="no">
```

It returned an array showing b, then a.

For displaying your column headers, you simply loop through this array.  Displaying the data would be slightly more complicated.  I would do something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="q1">
<cfloop array="#q1.getcolumnlist()#" index = "arrayElement">
#q1[arrayElement][currentrow]#
closing tags
```

Comment: That's not a ColdFusion function, it's a method on the underlying Java class that represents a ColdFusion query object. It's undocumented and unsupported. It will work, but one should tread with caution when using these functions, and if there's a native CFML function which can be used instead (like in this case, `getMetadata()` returns the info one needs), then one should always use the CFML function instead.

Comment: And here I am testing a conversion to Lucee. ACF and Lucee both use the syntax `query_name.columnList` to return a CSV list of column names. Calling the Java function `getColumnList()` doesn't work in Lucee.

Answer (score 2):

This answer seems too obvious to be the answer to your requirement, but I can't think what else you might mean. One loops over a recordset via the `<cfloop>` tag:

```
<cfloop query="showDeletedData"><!--- loop rows--->
    <cfloop array="#employeemeta#" index="col"><!--- loop columns--->
        <cfoutput>#showDeletedData[col][currentRow]#</cfoutput><!--- output value for the row/column --->
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It's also quite odd to couple your DB schema to your display requirements. Unless this is a web-based DB maintenance client, I guess.

Comment: No the problem is that coldfusion will show the columns in alphabetical order, and not in the order listed within the database.

Comment: `getMetadata()` returns the columns in the order they were specified *in the SQL statement*. If you are using `SELECT *` that will be in the order they are defined in the table create statement. If you have your columns listed differently in your `SELECT` statement you will have to query the DB a second time to get the ordering from the table itself.

Comment: *coldfusion will show the columns in alphabetical order* Did you actually try the code above or are you just assuming it behaves the same as using `query.columnList`?