# Output MySQL dynamically without column names using ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I want to dynamically output a table and it's data. I have the data source and the Table Name.

I was looking at using `<cftable>` but I am stuck with the dynamic column names.

This is basically what I want to do - it obviously does not work, but here for illustration purposes.

```
<cfset datasource = "test">
<cfset tablename = "mytable">

<!--- first get the columns from the table --->
<cfquery name="getcolumns" datasource="#datasource#">
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '#mytable#';
</cfquery>

<!--- Now select all from the table --->
<cfquery name="selectall" datasource="#datasource#">
SELECT      *
FROM        #mytable#
</cfquery>

<!--- Output all rows from the table --->
<cftable query="selectall">
  <cfoutput query="getcolumns">
     <cfcol text="#COLUMN_NAME#" header="#COLUMN_NAME#">
</cfoutput>
</cftable>
```

Comment: This question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601325/looping-columns-in-coldfusion-along-with-values-in-correct-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches you can use.  Documented feature `queryName.columnlist` gives you a list of all the column names in alphabetical order.  Undocumented feature `queryName.getcolumnlist()` gives you an array of all the column names in the order they appear in the select clause.

This allows you to do something like this.

```
<cfoutput query="queryName">
<cfloop list = "#queryName.columnlist#" index = "column">
#queryName[column][currentrow]#
closing tags
```